# How to upload image using express-fileupload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, file-upload

I want to upload an image to Cloudinary from the postman. I am using express-fileupload
library to handle multipart form. This is how my index.ts file looks like,

```
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
app.use(fileUpload());
```

In my controller function I am getting file object also like this,[image]

And this is how my controller looks like,

```
export const uploadImage = async (
  request: Request,
  response: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const files = request.files;
  console.log(files?.profileImage);
  response.send("image sent");
};
```

But the problem is when I access the path of that file which is not available in the file object and I want that file path to upload that file to Cloudinary.

```
files?.profileImage?.path // I got undefined here
```

Is this approach right? Or I am missing something or I should use multer to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: `request.file` or `request.files`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have to configure fileUpload middleware like this in the index.ts file,

```
app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));
```

Where "useTempFiles" has to be true. This will save the file temporarily on the server.